# Tkinter Can't figure out how to clear all the text in a Text widget and then immediately rewrite it

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm trying to clear and rewrite the text in a text widget in the same function. Here is the function.

Here's the function...

```
def delete_individual(self):
        """
        Deletes a single row in the SQL events table. The row is determined by entry in the individual
        DeleteRowEntry"""
        try:
            index = int(self.individualRowEntry.get())
        except ValueError:        
            tkm.showerror('Entry Error','Index entry should be an integer.',parent = self.parent)    
            return None

        conn = lite.connect('fit.db')
        cursor = conn.cursor()
        cursor.execute("""DELETE FROM events WHERE(id = (?))""",(index,))

        conn.commit()
        conn.close
        self.parent.entriesDisplayArea.delete('1.0',tk.END)
        self.parent.entriesDisplayArea.insert('1.1', #some text)
```

Basically the text just stays there, it isn't actually deleted until the Toplevel window containing the text widget is closed and reopened (which happens no matter what).

If I were to place the delete statement after the insert statement it WOULD delete, but thats not what I want, I want it to delete and then insert new text. Thanks in advance for any reply!

Comment: @abarnert: because `0` is not a valid index. For a text widget, the index of the very first character is `"1.0"`.

Comment: Cam you provide a complete working example that illustrates the problem? Based on what you posted it should work just fine. There must be more to your code than what you're showing. Also, are you running this on OSX by chance?

Comment: @BryanOakley: Sorry, thought he was using an `Entry`, not a `Text`. Probably because I saw the capitalized word "Entry" in the source (which is irrelevant, since it's inside a string…) and didn't think it through.